# Hiding button while its triggered method is running

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, xcode5

I have a button that triggers a method.  This method shows images (spaced out by a timer) and stops after a certain number of images has been shown.  Therefor, the button needs to be hidden after it is pressed so it cannot be pressed again and skip me into an infinite loop.  I would be open to any technique used to achieve this that does not utterly destroy efficiency.

Here is my attempt:

```
-(IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender {
 //hide spin button after press
 spinButton.hidden = YES;
// The count starts at 0, so initialize "count" to 0.
count = 0;
// Use an NSTimer to call displayPic: repeatedly every 1 second ("repeats" is set to "YES")
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(displayPic:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
//show button after method has fully executed
spinButton.hidden = NO;
```

I cannot get the button to disappear using my code provided above.  NOTE: If I leave out the last line (spinButton.hidden = NO;), the button disappears when presses the first time and never comes back up.

Comment: What about showing the button again when you stop the timer (after showing a certain number of images)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you just move `spinButton.hidden=NO` to `displayPic` (inside of an if that checks for count being high enough?)

Comment: That was my first attempt.  I went back to check if I just made a mistake the first time and found out that my spinButton.hidden=NO followed my invalidate timer in my if statement.  I switched the order and it works flawlessly! Sometimes you need another set of eyes.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the button and unhiding it again. The view never updates in-between the two and even if it was the method would be executed within a few milliseconds so you would´t be able to see it. You probably want to move the last line into another method e.g. your `displayPic:` method.